# IntelliJ Idea shortcuts with non US keyboard

Tags: eclipse, intellij-idea, keyboard-shortcuts

My Mac keyboard is a Portuguese one. Although it's QWERTY, many symbols are in different places (namely, Shift-some number). In Eclipse, if a shortcut involves a character which, in itself, is a combination of keys (e.g. '/', which is Shift-7) I can do, for instance, command-shift-7 to comment a piece of code.

In IDEA, however, this doesn't work. To go "back", the keyboard shortcut is command-[, but to get the '[' I have to press option/alt-8, and command-option-8 doesn't do the trick. Is there some option I can enable to make it work?

Answer (score 1):

IntelliJ has a few pre-configured keymaps. Maybe you are not using the best one for you or your keyboard. If you are used to working with eclipse, maybe you will like the Eclipse keymap better.

In addition you can create your own keymap by copying an existing one and modifying it.

The keymap settings are under File -> Settings... -> Keymap

More on that in the jetbrains site: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/configuring-keyboard-shortcuts.html

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it is not possible without some fiddling. Myself I have a Swedish keyboard, and I know that some German users were helped by this workaround. It is not a *solution*, as the IDEA keymap menu instructions will be inconsistent; Commenting code will not be possible by cmd+/ as the keymap settings will say, it will in practice be cmd+-. See [IDEA-63779](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-63779#tab=Comments) and [IDEA-165950](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-165950#comment=27-2053321) for more information.

**1. Install JB SDK Bintray Downloader by cmd+shift+a "plugins"**, and search for "bintray", select "JB SDK Bintray Downloader" and hit install.

**2. cmd+shift+a and enter "bintray"**.

**3.** In the pull down list, **select "jbsdk8u112b251_osx_x64.tar.gz"** or later. You will find it at next to the last in list. Hit "Download" and then "Install".

**4. Allow IDEA to restart**.

**5. Open menu IntelliJ IDEA -> About Intellij IDEA and verify** two things: (a) that JRE is of build ...819... and that JVM is "by JetBrains s.r.o.".

**6. Open Help -> Edit Custom Properties...** and have a new configuration created, enter:
    com.jetbrains.use.old.keyevent.processing=true

**7. Exit and restart**.